# Python Client - Clients keep losing connection to server after sending information to the server

Tags: python, sockets, server, connection, client

The code runs like this, I run the server then run two clients. Both clients connect to the server successfully. They both send a message to the server saying they are connected and receive the same message back. The second client is waiting to receive a message from the server at this point. Now the host presses the start game button. This sends a a message "start" to the server and it sends it back. This part is where the problem is because after the host client sends and receives start both clients lose connection to the server. Here is a clip of what I'm talking about. https://streamable.com/9ezps9.

Here is my server code

```
import _thread
import threading
import socket

server = ''
port = 9999
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
str(e)

print("Waiting for a connection, Server Started")
s.listen(2)

clients = set()
clients_lock = threading.Lock()

def threaded_client(client, address):
    print("Accepted connection from: ", address)
    with clients_lock:
        clients.add(client)
    try:
        while True:
            data = client.recv(1024)
            print("Received: ", data.decode())
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                print("Sending: ", data.decode())
                with clients_lock:
                    for c in clients:
                        c.sendall(data)
    except:
        print("Lost Connection")
        conn.close()
players = 0
while players != 2:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    players += 1
    _thread.start_new(threaded_client, (conn, addr))
```

Here is all my code which contains server communication

Network class for clients:
import socket

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = socket.gethostname()
        self.port = 9999
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            self.client.send(str.encode("Connected"))
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            data = data.decode()
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
    def recv(self):
        return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
```

For some context in this part there is a host game button and a join game button.
This code has the start game button which when pressed sends the message "start" and then both clients lose connection.
This bit of code runs after the host game button is pressed:

```
    class HostGamePage:
        def clearFrame(self):
        # destroy all widgets from frame
            for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy() 
       
        def __init__(self, root, frame):
            n = Network()
            n.connect()
            self.root = root
            self.frame = frame               
            self.start_game_button = Button(self.frame, padx=60, pady=40, text="Start Game", 
                                            command=lambda:[HostGamePage.clearFrame(self),
                                                            QuestionBoard(self.root,                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                            self.frame, 0),
                                                            n.send(str.encode("start"))])
    
            #Define Labels
            self.host_label = Label(self.frame,padx=40,pady=20,text="Waiting for Player 2")
            self.lobby_code_label = Label(self.frame,padx=40,pady=20,text="")
    
            #Configure Labels
            self.host_label.config(font = ('Heletica bold', 32))
    
            #Putting it all together
            self.host_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
            self.start_game_button.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

This part of the code runs after the join game button is pressed:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Nov 26 16:02:51 2021

@author: marquesk, gonzaleza15
"""
from tkinter import *
from network import Network
from recieve1 import Recieve

class JoinPage:
    
    def __init__(self, root, frame):
        n = Network()
        n.connect()
        self.root = root
        self.frame = frame
    
        self.joinLabel = Label(self.frame, text = "Looking for game to join...")
        self.joinLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        Recieve(n.recv(), self.root, self.frame)


    
    #Insert Network Functionality here
    
    #joinedLabel = Label(self.frame, text = "Game Found. Connecting")
```

Here is where the start game button leads to:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Nov 24 09:59:38 2021

@author: marquesk, gonzaleza15
"""

from question_page import *
from finalResults import *
from Question_Object_List import *
from itertools import groupby
from recieve2 import Recieve
from network import Network

# This is the Question Board Class. Within it, the class creates the entire gameboard that the players will see
# for their entire time playing the game. There are numerous functions, labels, and buttons that make up it's
# entire screen. See Comments for Details.


class QuestionBoard:

    # This function is used to check if all button widgets on the screen have been destroyed.
    # It's generic and requires an iterable variable.
    def all_equal(iterable):
        g = groupby(iterable)
        return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)

# Every widget in tkinter has a function called winfo_exists(). This function returns 1 if a widget
# is on screen and 0 if it's destroyed. This function type casts these values of 1's and 0's to
# create a boolean array that can be used to determine if all buttons on the screen have been destroyed.
    def makeBoolArray(self, lst):
        self.finalArray = []
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            self.question = lst[i]
            self.truthValue = bool(self.question.winfo_exists())
            self.finalArray.append(self.truthValue)
        return self.finalArray

# This function takes the boolean array of whether a widger or not exists and checks to see if all buttons on screen
# have been destroyed. If so, the gameboard GUI is completely cleared and the final results page is displayed.
    def checkClear(self, questionArray):
        booleanArray = QuestionBoard.makeBoolArray(self, questionArray)
        if QuestionBoard.all_equal(booleanArray):
            QuestionBoard.clearFrame(self)
            LeaderBoard(self.root, self.frame)

# This function clears the entire frame to make room for other GUI pages.
    def clearFrame(self):
        for widgets in self.frame.winfo_children():
            widgets.destroy()

# This is the constructor for the question board class. Within it, everything that the board displays is created.
    def __init__(self, root, frame, player):
        n = Network()
        self.root = root
        self.frame = frame

    # Create Labels
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text="Networks")
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame, text="Data Protocols")
        self.label3 = Label(self.frame, text="Commands")
        self.label4 = Label(self.frame, text="Trivia")

        # Put labels on the grid
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.label2.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.label3.grid(column=2, row=0)
        self.label4.grid(column=3, row=0)

# All the statements underneath this comment create and intialize all buttons seen on screen.
# Every command with in them opens a Question Page object with the root and a Question Object.
# It then destroys the button and checks if it was the final button to be destroyed.
# The .grid functions below each button places these buttons on the grid structure of the GUI page.

        self.network1 = Button(self.frame, text='100', width=15, height=5,
                               command=lambda: [QuestionPage.openQuestionWindow(self, root, networking1),
                                                self.network1.destroy(),
                                                self.checkClear(self.questionList),
                                                Recieve(n.send(str.encode(networking1)), root, networking1)])
        self.network1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.network2 = Button(self.frame, text='200', width=15, height=5,
                               command=lambda: [QuestionPage.openQuestionWindow(self, root, networking2),
                                                self.network2.destroy(),
                                                self.checkClear(self.questionList),
                                                Recieve(n.send(str.encode(networking1)), root, networking1)])
        self.network2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.data1 = Button(self.frame, text='100', width=15, height=5,
                            command=lambda: [QuestionPage.openQuestionWindow(self, root, data1),
                                             self.data1.destroy(),
                                             self.checkClear(self.questionList),
                                             Recieve(n.send(str.encode(networking1)), root, networking1)])
        self.data1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.data2 = Button(self.frame, text='200', width=15, height=5,
                            command=lambda: [QuestionPage.openQuestionWindow(self, root, data2),
                                             self.data2.destroy(),
                                             self.checkClear(self.questionList),
                                             Recieve(n.send(str.encode(networking1)), root, networking1)])
        self.data2.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.command1 = Button(self.frame, text='100', width=15, height=5,
                               command=lambda: [QuestionPage.openQuestionWindow(self, root, commands1),
                                                self.command1.destroy(),
                                                self.checkClear(self.questionList),
                                                Recieve(n.send(str.encode(networking1)), root, networking1)])
        self.command1.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.command2 = Button(self.frame, text='200', width=15, height=5,
                               command=lambda: [QuestionPage.openQuestionWindow(self, root, commands2),
                                                self.command2.destroy(),
                                                self.checkClear(self.questionList),
                                                Recieve(n.send(str.encode(networking1)), root, networking1)])
        self.command2.grid(column=2, row=2, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.trivia1 = Button(self.frame, text='100', width=15, height=5,
                              command=lambda: [QuestionPage.openQuestionWindow(self, root, trivia1),
                                               self.trivia1.destroy(),
                                               self.checkClear(self.questionList),
                                               Recieve(n.send(str.encode(networking1)), root, networking1)])
        self.trivia1.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.trivia2 = Button(self.frame, text='200', width=15, height=5,
                              command=lambda: [QuestionPage.openQuestionWindow(self, root, trivia2),
                                               self.trivia2.destroy(),
                                               self.checkClear(self.questionList),
                                               Recieve(n.send(str.encode(networking1)), root, networking1)])
        self.trivia2.grid(column=3, row=2, padx=20, pady=10)

# Below this comment is a list variable. It creates a list of all the buttons created above.
# It had to be located inside the constructor.so that it may be passed to the "checkClear" function
# so that it can create a Boolean array so it can then be evaluated
# if all buttons are destroyed, which will display the leaderboard and end the game.
        self.questionList = [self.network1, self.network2, self.data1, self.data2, self.command1, self.command2,
                             self.trivia1, self.trivia2]
        if player == 1:
            n.recv()
        print(networking2)
```

Here is the recieve import:

```
from question_board import *


class Recieve:
    def __init__(self, data, root, frame):
        self.data = data
        self.root = root
        self.frame = frame

        if self.data == "start":
            for widgets in self.frame.winfo_children():
                widgets.destroy()
            QuestionBoard(self.root, self.frame, 1)
```

Comment: Have you removed the bare `except:` so you can see the cause of the lost connection?

Comment: @MarkTolonen removed the except and i got the error: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine     Its giving me the error on the data = client.recv()